# Python, how to iterate hex values in a tkinter spinbox widget

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I have a function that gets 'start', 'finish' values and need to create a Spinbox widget. The values may be hex or integer with increment of 1.

When i get integers(ex: start = 1, finish = 6) it works great.
But when I get hex values (ex: start = 0x0, finish = 0xf) i get the following error:

`_tkinter.TclError: bad spinbox format specifier "%.2x"`

What is the right format to make it iterate on hex values?
I used this link as reference [nmt.edu Spinbox](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/spinbox.html)

code:

```
def create_spinbox(self,min_value,max_value):
    self.current_value = StringVar()
    self.current_value.set(min_value)

    if re.match(r'^\s*(0[xX][0-9a-fA-F]+)\s*', min_value):  # hex index
        Spinbox(self.master,
               from_=min_value, to=max_value, width=5,
               format='%.2x',
               textvariable=self.corrent_value,
               command=lambda: self.update_loop_index())
    else:  # int index
        Spinbox(self.master, from_=min_value, to=max_value, width=2,
               textvariable = self.current_value,
               command = lambda: self.update_loop_index())
```

I also tried to solve this problem by using spinbox with 'values' instead of from_/to

code:

```
def __init__(self,parent):
    self.master = parent
    self.variable_dict = dict()
    self.loop_value_frame = LabelFrame(self.master, text="Loop Variables: ", bg='white')
    self.loop_value_frame.grid(row=3, column=0, padx=5, sticky='we')


def add_loop_variable(self, min_value, max_value):
    self.variable_dict["min_value"] = min_value
    self.variable_dict["max_value"] = max_value
    self.variable_dict["current_value"] = StringVar()
    self.variable_dict["current_value"].set(min_value)

def clear(self):
    for widget in self.loop_value_frame.winfo_children():
        widget.destroy()
    self.loop_value_frame.grid_forget()    # remove from view

def create_spinbox(self):
    self.clear() # clear the frame


    if re.match(r'^\s*(0[xX][0-9a-fA-F]+)\s*', variable_dict["min_value"]):  # hex index
        int_base = 16
    else:  # int index
        int_base = 10   
    index_list = [index if int_base==10 else hex(index) for index in range(int(self.variable_dict["min_value"],int_base),int(self.variable_dict["max_value"],int_base)+1)]      # parse the index list
    Spinbox(self.loop_value_frame, values=tuple(index_list), width=5,
              textvariable = self.variable_dict["current_value"],
              command = lambda: self.update_loop_index())

def update_loop_index(self):

    # do some calculation on the new index to display

    self.create_spinbox() # display the whole widget again
```

This code doesn't get errors. But it doesnt work with the StringVar(). Pressing the up/down in the spinbox doesn't update the spinbox display, although when i read the value stored in the `current_value` is shows the new value. 
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: So, your spinbox will create a new spinbox every time the value changes? Why would you do that? And why do you have this potentially infinite number of spinboxes all use the same variable?

Comment: Everytime the user changes the index, it clears the widget window (erase all the tk widget within it, including the spinbox) and create a new one with updated values. The StrignVar is property and not being erased, it should keep the current data .. but it returns to the default value..

Comment: The code you showed doesn't do that. Please provide a [mcve]. Though, I don't see the point in destroying a widget only to recreate it exactly. If you need to change the from/to values, you don't need to destroy it and recreate it.

Comment: You're right. I changed the clear function, to clear and update only the widgets that should change instead of clearing and redrawing the whole frame. It fixed the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The format specifier doesn't support `%x`. From the official tcl/tk documentation:

> **format** Specifies an alternate format to use when setting the string value when using the -from and -to range. This must be a format specifier of the form %.f, as it will format a floating-point number.

When I paste the code at the bottom of your question into a program and make reasonable assumptions about the missing code, the spinbox works fine and the `StringVar` is properly updated.

Comment: I checked the second code, and when I remove the `command = lambda: self.update_loop_index()` it works fine. But with the command I get the problem. the `update_loop_index()` function holds a recursion of the the `create_spinbox` (I edited the post). Is there a way to make it work with the recursion?